# replacing the content of a program dynamically upon the output of grep

Tags: linux, bash, shell

a.cpp

```
int main()
{
    bool b;
    bool c = true;

    bool  d;
    bool e ;
    bool  f  ;

    int x = 3;

    std::cout << "x is " << x << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

grepping for c files which have boolean variables without definition.

```
grep -rn --include \*.cpp --include \*.c bool | grep -v 'svn\|virtual\|::' | grep 'bool\([ ]\+[A-Z0-9a-z_]*[ ]*\);'
```

output

```
a.cpp:3:        bool b;
a.cpp:6:        bool  d;
a.cpp:7:        bool e ;
a.cpp:8:        bool  f  ;
```

Now I wanted to modify these lines to

```
bool b=false;
bool d=false;
bool e=false;
bool f=false;
```

using an command.

Can somebody suggest an approach. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following command will replace directly in files and create backup filename.BAK, `-i.BAK`, `-i` without extension doesn't backup.

`directory_path` must be replaced with the path  `.` if current

```
find directory_path \( -name '*.c' -o -name '*.cpp' \) -exec perl -i.BAK -pe '
    s/^(\s+bool\s+\w+)\s+(;)\s+$/$1=false$2/
' {} +
```

to revert if something goes wrong

```
find directory_path -name '*.BAK' -exec bash -c 'mv $1 ${1%.BAK}' -- {} \;
```

to remove .BAK

```
find directory_path -name '*.BAK' -exec rm {} +
```

Note: the difference the last argument of find `+` or `\;` is that last {} find will fork less processes with `+` because {} will be replaced by as many arguments as command line can contain (like xargs).

Comment: hi, it is working but not fully...
        bool b=false;
        bool c = true;

        bool  d=false;
        bool e ;
        bool  f  ;
e,f does not change their values

Comment: i forgot `\( \)` around `-name -o -name`, *.c files not processed updated

Comment: @naren following your comment, is there any spaces after semi-colon `;` and before new line

Comment: if it's the case remove end of line anchor `$` : `s/(^\s+bool\s+\w+)(;)/$1=false$2/` but if there is many instructions on the same line only the first will be changed

Comment: no there are not any, bool e ; and bool  f  ;
before and after e there is one space and before and after f there are two spaces.

Comment: in fact it is due to space between name and semi-colon, i'm updating answer

Comment: now it works perfectly.. thanks.. I need to apply this for bunch of files... thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can try this `sed`:

```
sed  -i.bak 's/^\(\s*bool \+[a-zA-Z0-9_]\)\s*;$/\1=false;/' my.cpp
```

Note: First try with sample files. Then apply in live source code.